# How can I protect an answer?

Tags: support

I just saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/722928/1) and edited it to [this](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/722928/2) to allow the next user in the review queue to see that it really *is an answer*, but I'm fearing that the answer (though off-topic as custom kernel) might be [lost to <s>GNU</s> herd mentality](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/515080).

*How do I protect an **answer**?*

Comment: so.. basically you want to impose your opinion on the reviewers and stop it from being deleted?

Comment: :D Not *really*, but there is a germ of truth in your opinion...  I've upvoted the A in the mean time and favourited the question.  I just felt sad for the low rep user that his first answer will be deleted and we might turn him away from here. @Seth

Comment: Then I guess I'm a little unclear on what your post is about... Sure, I don't want users to leave. Hence you editing and commenting! FWIW it left the review queue and now that its score >-1 it can't be deleted except by a moderator.

Comment: So, I guess, the best way to "protect" an answer is to do just what you did!

Comment: Good news!  :-)  Thanbks for the effort and sorry about the dumb question...  Just leaving it in for posterity and upvoting your comment!  >:)

Answer (score 1):

### What??? You want to protect a single answer?

**That would be dictatorially imposing your opinion on the reviewers and stop it from being reviewed!**

If the answer is that good, edit it, improve the grammar, spelling and readability and upvote it instead!